# Busqueda entre fechas sql diferente formato

Tags: sql, sql-server

El problema viene al hacer una búsqueda de datos en la bbdd. Se esta guardando un Timestring con formato `'YYYY-MM-DD H:MM:SS'`.
Este formato se guarda desde las 00:00 hasta las 09:59, después ya se me guarda con el formato `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`

Al ser formato diferentes cuando busco los registros entre esa dos fechas me aparece en blanco. Como hago para que funcione correctamente?

Esta es la consulta que estoy haciendo

```sql
SELECT TOP (1000) [VarName] ,[TimeString] ,[VarValue] ,[Validity] ,[Time_ms] 
FROM [REGISTROS].[dbo].[RT_REGISTROS0] 
where Timestring Between '2022-07-20 9:37:04' and '2022-07-20 15:48:58'
```

Comment: Por favor, aporta unos datos de ejemplo para entender tu problema...

Comment: Esa instruccion TOP e identificadores dbo. me suenan más a MS SQLServer que MySql.

Comment: Cuando pongo el primer Timestring con un 0 delante del 9 si que me hace la busqueda pero solamente aparecen registros de las 10:00:00 hacia adelante

Comment: y ese campo de que tipo es?

Comment: Es de tipo char

Comment: y esto es mysql o sqlserver?

Comment: Es sql server, tengo un app de escritorio que se conecta a traves de ODBC a la bbdd, y ver los registros estoy usando Management Studio

Comment: pero la etiquetaste como mysql... ya te lo habian preguntado hace 1 hora...

Comment: Esta vez te ayudaron con las etiquetas; ten en cuenta que las etiquetas correctas resaltan tu pregunta para las personas con más conocimiento en una u otra tecnología. Usar cualquier cosa hace que no llegue la ayuda a ti. Puedes [edit] la pregunta todo lo que quieras y necesites para hacer que sea clara y te puedan responder

Answer (score 1):

Si el formato de hora estuviese [como debe ser](https://www.google.com/search?q=datetime+sql+format) sería sencillo y directo hacer la consulta, acostumbrate a [seguir estándares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times).

No se qué tan costoso sea para la BD la siguiente consulta, pero podrías hacer una conversión del campo `TimeString` a DATETIME para hacer las comparaciones:

```
     TimeString        VarValue
+---------------------+--------+
| 2022-07-20 3:15:36  | Value6 |
| 2022-07-20 9:48:40  | Value7 |
| 2022-07-20 12:06:25 | Value8 |
| 2022-07-20 16:18:41 | Value9 |
+---------------------+--------+
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM RT_REGISTROS0 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, TimeString) 
BETWEEN '2022-07-20 9:37:04' AND '2022-07-20 15:48:58'
```

En este enlace para [verlo en acción](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f8237/2/0), da como resultado:

```
      TimeString       VarValue
+---------------------+--------+
| 2022-07-20 9:48:40  | Value7 |
| 2022-07-20 12:06:25 | Value8 |
+---------------------+--------+
```